# Application layout combobox.SelectedValue for SearchBar

Tags: xpages

[image]

1. How can I get the value of `SearchBar` in Application Layout?
2. If I have more than one criteria to search (in application layout) how to get the current (selected)  value of combobox near the `SearchBar`?

Have a look on the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic assumption behind the search bar with options is that you'll submit the search information to another XPage. For instance;

```
<xe:this.searchBar>
    <xe:appSearchBar
        pageName="/search1.xsp">
        <xe:this.options>
            <xe:basicLeafNode
                label="People"
                submitValue="people">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode
                label="Buildings"
                submitValue="buildings">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.options>
    </xe:appSearchBar>
</xe:this.searchBar>
```

Such a markup will create a combobox with two options. When the user submits the search string, it will navigate to `/search1.xsp?search=SomeValue&option=buildings`. Therefore, you will process those values inside the target page.

In such a case I guess you'll want to decide which view to be searched according to the search option. What I do is generally having a single XPage for search results and different custom controls for different views. You might use a switch or dynamic control component depending on the case. Alternatively, you can use the dynamic view panel component to switch between different views.

If you prefer different search pages for different search options (i.e. searchPeople.xsp and searchBuildings.xsp), you'll have two options. You can design an intermediate page to redirect the user to the desired page or you can create your own search box there. So you don't generally need to have the option value within the page.

BTW, that value is available at the Client-side JavaScript. That's a `<select>` element and its id is "the id of the application layout control" + "_searchopt". You can refer to the client-side object with `dojo.byId("#{id:applicationLayout1}_searchopt")`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Serdar; Thank you so much. I did the same thing but a little bit different. I redirected to another search page and get the value from the link. then I could make what kind of search i wanted to do :)